# Create an Empty Row in between 2 Datasets in DataWeave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I would like to create an empty row in between 2 data sets. Attempted to create empty variable but it doesnt work.

**Attempted:**

```
var empty = [""]
---
(vars.header1 default[]) ++
(vars.data1 default[]) ++
empty ++
(vars.header2 default[]) ++
(vars.data1 default[])
```

**Desired output:**

[image]

Comment: You are missing the input

Comment: As well are there any conditions that need to be kept in mind ?

Comment: inputs are the variables, i am able to stack header1, data1, header2 and data 2 together, now just left the empty row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb always paste the input (it would be hard to guess what you have in your variables) and the expected output out of Dataweave.

To add an empty row try setting your empty variable to [{}] and give it a shot.

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv

---
[{
    "a":"1",
    "b":"2"
}]
++
[{}]
++
[{"c":"c","d":"d","e":"e"}]
++
[{
    "c":"3",
    "d":"4",
    "e":"5"
}]
```

**Output**

```
a,b
1,2

c,d,e
3,4,5
```